# Spark Context tuning

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I work on Python application build in Jupyter Environment (ipynb Notebook). Environment starts into Docker Container. My client connect to Cassandra DB by pyspark cassandra driver, but execution is very slow (maybe there is an overhead). I found, and change the spark.sql.shuffle.partitions, because by default this value is setting to 200. Despite the change, time is reduce but are yet slow. What about other tuning spark params?

**spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 4**

*This my python code for Spark Configuration*

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster(environment.get('forecast.spark.master'))
conf.setAppName("Consolidate and Evaluate Data")
conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", environment.get('cassandra.port'))
conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", environment.get('cassandra.host'))
#Spark Context
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", environment.get('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions'))
```

Comment: It's too broad for SO. Please provide more details, environement, code, etc. with more specific question

Comment: Environment : Jupyter on Docker (4 core , 4GB RAM)